# Magento 2 will only load on HTTPS after Varnish configuration attempt

Tags: cache, https, varnish

After trying to setup Varnish with Magento 2, and going through a series of edit to apache2 files as shown in tutorials from different websites, the site will now only load on HTTPS and return a 502 Gateway nginx error when accessed over HTTP.

**This is from error.log.1 in /var/log/nginx & SSH command netstat -plunt:**

```
2017/11/05 19:49:39 [error] 26727#0: *8028 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 149.56.127.166, server: , request: "HEAD /robots.txt HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://77.68.82.245:7080/robots.txt"
2017/11/05 20:19:08 [error] 26727#0: *8239 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 155.94.88.58, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://77.68.82.245:7080/"

netstat -plunt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1416/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      827/named
tcp        0      0 77.68.82.245:443        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1033/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1002/config
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4190            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      983/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      983/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      983/dovecot
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1416/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      983/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      983/dovecot
tcp        0      0 77.68.82.245:80         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1033/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8880            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1002/config
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      827/named
tcp        0      0 77.68.82.245:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      827/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      827/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      928/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      1002/config
tcp6       0      0 :::4190                 :::*                    LISTEN      983/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      983/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      983/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::7081                 :::*                    LISTEN      1087/apache2
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          :::*                    LISTEN      947/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::106                  :::*                    LISTEN      1023/xinetd
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      983/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      983/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1087/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::8880                 :::*                    LISTEN      1002/config
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      1023/xinetd
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      827/named
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      928/sshd
udp        0      0 172.17.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*                           827/named
udp        0      0 77.68.82.245:53         0.0.0.0:*                           827/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           827/named
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           688/dhclient
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                827/named
```

Does someone gone through this before and could help?

Thanks in advance,
Cristi

Comment: what is on port 7080 ???

Comment: When I try this command: sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 7080 nothing shows up.